# Google Calendar API V3: Recurring Event Edits

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I have an application I'm writing where I use Google Calendar Api (via PHP) to do some administration to my business Google Calendar events.

Everything seems to work well on singular events (events that do not reoccur). However, when I go in and programatically edit the instances of recurring events it seems to break the recurring events into singular events.

The recurring event ID still seems to be attached to the instances but events seem to be treated as singular events because all the instances now show up when I list the events of a calendar.

Previously to updating the description of instances, the parent/main event was the only event to show up in the event list for a calendar; now the main event and the instances show up in the list and in Google Calendar it no longer seems as if I have the ability to edit the recurring event, only the individual instances.

Has anyone had the problem of updating recurring instances of an event and it (for lack of a better word) breaking the recurrence?

Im using V3 of Google calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)