# Google Calendar API V3 - How to copy recurring events to other calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have written a GAS that copies all events from one calendar to another calendar within a date range, using API V3. So far so good.
The trouble is managing recurring events, as the `recurringEventId` property may not be managed manually. Basically recurring events on source calendar are treated as single events in the new calendar and `recurringEventId` cannot be changed as "immutable".

Any idea?

Similar to: [Google Calendar API V3: Recurring Event Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369730/google-calendar-api-v3-recurring-event-edits)

```
function DuplicateCalendars() {
  var calendarIdFrom = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com'; 
  var calendarIdTo = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy@group.calendar.google.com'; 
  // August 31, 2017 08:00:00 AM
  var start = new Date("2017-08-31T00:01:00Z");
  // August 30, 2018 11:30:00 PM
  var end = new Date("2018-08-31T00:00:00Z");
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: start.toISOString(),
    timeMax: end.toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 5,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };
  var newCalendarEvent;
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarIdFrom, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;

  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      newCalendarEvent = {
        "created": event.created,
        "summary": event.summary,
        "description": event.description,
        "location": event.location,
        "colorId": event.colorId,
        "creator": event.creator,
        "organizer": event.organizer,
        "start": event.start,
        "end": event.end,
        "endTimeUnspecified": event.endTimeUnspecified,
        "reminders": event.reminders,
        "attachments": event.attachments,
        "recurrence": event.recurrence
      };
      if (typeof event.recurringEventId !== 'undefined'){
        // what can I do????????
      }
      newCalendarEvent = Calendar.Events.insert(newCalendarEvent, calendarIdTo, {
           supportsAttachments: true
      });
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No upcoming events found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a tough case!

Comment: Maybe @Serge Insas has some ideas?